# Converting java.util.Function to non-Lambda expression one in Monad example taken from Wikipedia

Tags: java, function, lambda, monads

There is a very simple Monad example, written in Java, which is taken from Wikipedia article.

```
import java.util.function.Function;

interface Monad<T> {
    <U> Monad<U> bind(Function<T, Monad<U>> f);
}

class Maybe<T> implements Monad<T> {

    private final T val;

    public Maybe(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> Monad<U> bind(Function<T, Monad<U>> f) {
        if (val == null)
            return new Maybe<U>(null);
        return f.apply(val);
    }
}

public class MonadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maybe<Integer> x = new Maybe<>(5);
        Monad<Integer> y = x
                .bind(v -> new Maybe<>(v + 1))
                .bind(v -> new Maybe<>(v * 2));

        System.out.println( ((Maybe<Integer>)y).getVal() );
    }
}
```

For scholar purposed I'm trying to rewrite it without lambda expression for old Java 1.7 version.

My code looks like

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class MonadFunction implements Function<T, Monad<U>>{
    
    Monad<U> apply(T val) { return Monad<U>(val + 1); }
    
}

interface Monad<T> {
    <U> Monad<U> bind(Function<T, Monad<U>> f);
}

class Maybe<T> implements Monad<T> {

    private final T val;

    public Maybe(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    @Override
    public <U> Monad<U> bind(Function<T, Monad<U>> f) {
        if (val == null)
            return new Maybe<U>(null);
        return f.apply(val);
    }
}

public class MonadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maybe<Integer> x = new Maybe<>(5);
 
        Monad<Integer> y = x.bind(new MonadFunction())
        
        System.out.println( ((Maybe<Integer>)y).getVal() );
    }
}
```

where I have replaced functions (in my case just first one) with

```
class MonadFunction implements Function<T, Monad<U>>{

    Monad<U> apply(T val) { return Monad<U>(val + 1); }

}
```

however both offline and online compilers return errors `/MonadApp.java:3: error: cannot find symbol class MonadFunction implements Function<T, Monad<U>>{` and  `symbol: class U /MonadApp.java:5: error: cannot find symbol Monad<U> apply(T val) { return Monad<U>(val + 1); }`

The question is what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: A ton. `Function` does not exist in java 1.7 at all, so you can't use it (You can make your own, of course). The synax `return Monad<U>(val + 1);` isn't even legal java. Did you mean `return new Monad<U>(val + 1);` perhaps? That still doesn't work - val's type is `T`, could be anything. "Anything" is not guaranteed to have a meaningful interaction with "+1". So that code makes no semantic sense whatsoever.

Comment: Implementing Monads is harder than that, but really, you don't want to create a class called `MonadFunction`.  Really, just create your own `Function` interface and keep everything else the same.

Comment: Cheers. Just for now, I'm not looking for val + 1 or any other operation, but a way to make lambda expressions  free code. For example,
 
`class FunctionWithoutLambda implements Function<String, Integer> {

  FunctionWithoutLambda() { }
  
  Integer apply(String string_) { return string_.length(); } 
    
}`

works fine with at least 1.8, pretty sure that it's a generic types issue.

Comment: The `MonadFunction` class doesn’t define `T`. Please clarify: do you actually need this to work with Java 1.7 or are you just looking to make it work in 1.8 without using lambdas?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to make this work in Java 8 without the use of lambdas, you can also create a class that implements `Function`:

```java
class Adder implements Function<Integer, Monad<Integer>> {
    private final int num;

    Adder(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    @Override
    public Monad<Integer> apply(Integer integer) {
        return new Maybe<>(integer + num);
    }
}

public class MonadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maybe<Integer> x = new Maybe<>(5);
        Monad<Integer> y = x
                .bind(new Adder(1))
                .bind(new Adder(2));

        System.out.println( ((Maybe<Integer>)y).getVal() );
    }
}
```

In this case, the definitions of `Monad` and `Maybe` are unchanged.

If it does need to work with Java 7, `java.util.function.Function` is not available, but you can easily define an identical interface yourself:

```java
interface Function<T, U> {
    U apply(T value);
}
```

If you use this interface instead of `java.util.function.Function`, this will work with both Java 7 and Java 8, even with lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed for a couple of reasons:

1. You can implement monadic types in Java but you can't usefully express the fact that your type is a `Monad`, because the return type of the bind method needs to be M (M being the actual monad type), not `Monad<U>`. This isn't possible to express in Java due to the absence of higher-kinded types. You also can't capture the fact that the monad type needs to have a static `pure` method (sometimes called `return` or `unit`).
2. Your `MonadFunction` type isn't valid Java, as the generic type parameters, T & U aren't declared (the class declaration should start with `class MonadFunction<T, U>`). Even if you fix that you'll then still have the above issue.

However, you can express your `Maybe` class without recourse to Lambda functions quite easily once you throw away the `Monad` type:

```
class Maybe<T> {

    private final T val;

    public Maybe(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public T getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public <U> Maybe<U> bind(Function<T, Maybe<U>> f) {
        if (val == null)
            return new Maybe<U>(null);
        else
            return f.apply(val);
    }
}

public class MonadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Maybe<Integer> x = new Maybe<>(5);

        Maybe<String> y = x.bind(new Function<Integer, Maybe<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Maybe<String> apply(Integer i) {
                return i == 0 ? new Maybe<>(null) : new Maybe<>(i.toString());
            }
        });

        System.out.println(y.getVal());
    }
}
```